# Unable to run grails command on new project on Mac due to "Could not determine java version" error

Tags: java, macos, grails, installation, setup-project

I need to do run an existing grails project (which was running on windows) on a Mac system.

Before that, I am trying to setup grails and run a "hello world". I downloaded and installed grails using sdkman. My setup directory is -

/Users/sandeepan.nath/Desktop/setups
where I have created grails directory and ran the sdk install grails command which installed grails and created these -

```
SandeepanNath:grails sandeepan.nath$ ls -lrth
total 80
-rw-r--r--   1 sandeepan.nath  1974079253    73B Jun  1 13:03 gradle.properties
drwxr-xr-x   3 sandeepan.nath  1974079253    96B Jun  1 13:03 gradle
-rwxr--r--   1 sandeepan.nath  1974079253   4.9K Jun  1 13:03 gradlew
-rwxr--r--   1 sandeepan.nath  1974079253   2.3K Jun  1 13:03 gradlew.bat
-rwxr--r--   1 sandeepan.nath  1974079253   4.6K Jun  1 13:03 grailsw
-rwxr--r--   1 sandeepan.nath  1974079253   2.3K Jun  1 13:03 grailsw.bat
drwxr-xr-x   5 sandeepan.nath  1974079253   160B Jun  1 13:03 src
-rw-r--r--   1 sandeepan.nath  1974079253   5.3K Jun  1 13:03 grails-wrapper.jar
drwxr-xr-x  12 sandeepan.nath  1974079253   384B Jun  1 13:03 grails-app
-rw-r--r--   1 sandeepan.nath  1974079253   2.9K Jun  1 13:03 build.gradle
drwxr-xr-x   2 sandeepan.nath  1974079253    64B Jun  1 13:03 build
```

I ran grails create-app hello to create a project while inside the grails directory, but it failed -

```
SandeepanNath:hello sandeepan.nath$ grails create-app hello
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/Users/sandeepan.nath/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.3.10/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy/jars/groovy-2.4.17.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
| Error Error initializing classpath: Could not determine java version from '12.0.1'. (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

I went one level up, outside the grails directory, and created project (worked) -

```
SandeepanNath:setups sandeepan.nath$ grails create-app new_proj
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/Users/sandeepan.nath/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.3.10/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy/jars/groovy-2.4.17.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
| Application created at /Users/sandeepan.nath/Desktop/setups/new_proj
```

and followed the steps to create a project as in https://docs.grails.org/3.3.10/guide/single.html#creatingAnApplication.

Now, when I am inside new_proj, and try running grails command, I am blocked here -

```
SandeepanNath:new_proj sandeepan.nath$ grails
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/Users/sandeepan.nath/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.3.10/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy/jars/groovy-2.4.17.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
| Error Error initializing classpath: Could not determine java version from '12.0.1'. (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

I have Java home set in the environment PATH variable -

```
SandeepanNath:~ sandeepan.nath$ echo $PATH
/Users/sandeepan.nath/.sdkman/candidates/grails/current/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/apache-maven/bin:/usr/libexec/java_home/bin:/opt/apache-maven/bin:/usr/libexec/java_home:/opt/apache-maven/bin
```

Note - there is no such path as /usr/libexec/java_home/bin

Still, when I try running `grails` command from within my project, I get this `Could not determine java version` error -

```
SandeepanNath:new_proj sandeepan.nath$ grails --stacktrace
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/Users/sandeepan.nath/.sdkman/candidates/grails/3.3.10/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy/jars/groovy-2.4.17.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
| Error Error initializing classpath: Could not determine java version from '12.0.1'. (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not determine java version from '12.0.1'.
    at org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.toVersion(JavaVersion.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.current(JavaVersion.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.jvm.UnsupportedJavaRuntimeException.assertUsingVersion(UnsupportedJavaRuntimeException.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ConnectorServices.checkJavaVersion(ConnectorServices.java:66)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ConnectorServices.close(ConnectorServices.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultGradleConnector.close(DefaultGradleConnector.java:57)
    at org.grails.cli.gradle.cache.CachedGradleOperation.call(CachedGradleOperation.groovy:78)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.populateContextLoader(GrailsCli.groovy:525)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.initializeProfile(GrailsCli.groovy:508)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.initializeApplication(GrailsCli.groovy:306)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:269)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:159)
```

Comment: Since the error originates from gradle, you might get lucky with a newer gradle version.  But in the past i had no luck with that (lost code reloading with the newes 4.X gradle).

Comment: Thanks, I had to install gradle as well. The above observation was with gradle not installed.

Comment: After downgrading JDK, I had to create a new app via create-app, otherwise I was getting errors.

Comment: @cfrick "...you might get lucky with a newer gradle version" - Upgrading Gradle is not going to fix this problem.  It will create other problems and won't solve this one.

Comment: 3.5 is the recommended Gradle version for Grails 3.3.8.

Comment: @Dave's answer below is correct.  We support Java 7 and 8 with Grails 3.3.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install JDK 8 from Oracle,  once installed you should be ok.  Grails 3 requires 7 or 8.